# How can concatenate all values in a new object while grouping via Object B

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm trying to manipulate some raw data into a more meaningful output.  I'm looking to concatenate values in column B based on Column A.

For example

```
Col A   Col B  
user1   action1
user1   action2
user1   action3
user1   action4
user2   action10
user3   action4
user4   action5
user4   action1
```

Into something like

```
User1  action1 > action2 > action3 > action4
User2  action10 
User3  action4
User4  action5 > action1
```

Comment: You would need `aggregate(Col_B  ~ Col_A, your_data, paste, collapse = " > ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
     group_by(Col_A) %>% 
     summarize(Col_B = paste0(Col_B, collapse = " > "))
```

Comment: Maybe mention that you need library(dplyr) to execute